# Why YAMLGenerator dont close stream depends on configuration

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

When creating objectMapper with yaml factory there are couple of configuration parameters which you can set:

```
   ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    // o.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);
    // o.enable(SerializationFeature.CLOSE_CLOSEABLE);
```

problem is that this configuration is ignored in YAML Generator:

```
 @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        if (!isClosed()) {
            _emitter.emit(new DocumentEndEvent(null, null, false));
            _emitter.emit(new StreamEndEvent(null, null));
            super.close();
            _writer.close();
        }
    }
```

even when in javadoc is written something else

> void com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.close()
>   throws IOException
>
> Method called to close this generator, so that no more content can be
>   written.
>
> Whether the underlying target (stream, writer) gets closed depends on
>   whether this generator either manages the target (i.e. is the only one
>   with access to the target -- case if caller passes a reference to the
>   resource such as File, but not stream); or has feature
>   Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET enabled. If either of above is true, the
>   target is also closed. Otherwise (not managing, feature not enabled),
>   target is not closed.

Comment: Calling code may want to write something after this YAML document. E.g. the output stream may be for writing HTTP servlet response. HTTP response may have some headers that go after the response payload. Maybe there are other use cases. However I would agree that there could be a better solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, the javadoc isn't written in the `YAMLGenerator` class but in jackson core's [`JsonGenerator` interface](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.java#L1780) which `YAMLGenerator` implements by extending `GeneratorBase`.

Comment: yes and when you extending method in JSON generator you should follow javadoc in method which you want to override. Or not ?

Comment: Sure, or at the very least write a javadoc that underlines the fact that you're not following it and why. But what I meant is that a derivation from a javadoc is more understandable (either as a mistake or design choice) when it's the javadoc of the interface of a class from another project than when it's your own.

Comment: use this code `YAMLMapper o = new YAMLMapper();
  o.configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER, true);
  o.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);
  o.enable(SerializationFeature.CLOSE_CLOSEABLE);`

Answer (score 1):

Use YAML Mapper instead of Object Mapper. This works fine for me.

```
YAMLMapper yamlMapper = new YAMLMapper(); 
yamlMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false); 
yamlMapper.configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER, true);
yamlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.CLOSE_CLOSEABLE);
```